# Is there a faster alternative to geometry shaders that can render points as a specific number of triangles?

Tags: opengl, vulkan, geometry-shader, tessellation

I'm currently using openGL with a geometry shader to take points and convert them to triangles during rendering.

I have n lists of points that will each be rendered as n triangles (first list of points each becomes one triangle, second becomes two triangles, etc). I've tried swapping geometry shaders for each of these lists with max_vertices being the minimum for each list. With OpenGL I seemingly have no control over how this is ultimately implemented on the GPU via the geometry shader and some drivers seem to handle it very slowly while others are very fast.

Is there any way to perform this specific task optimally, ideally taking advantage of the fact that I know the exact number of desired output triangles per element and in total? I would be happy to use some alternative to geometry shaders for this if possible. I would also be happy to try Vulkan if it can do the trick.

Comment: How do you render a point "as a triangle"? What does that mean?

Comment: There is a conversion from point to triangle in the geometry shader. The points are stored as information about the triangles to-be drawn.

Comment: I don't fully understand what that means. I mean, I get the idea that you have a GS that takes a point primitive and spits out some number of triangles. I just don't get *how* that works. Are all of the positions part of that "point" and the GS simply fishes them out? Is it computing triangles that face towards the camera with some specific world-space distance?

Comment: Or do you just want to look at it as a completely arbitrary function `f(vindex, tindex)`, where `vindex` are the indices of the vertex within the triangle (0-2), and `tindex` is one of the triangles that the point is supposed to generate. And the mechanics of the generation should be treated as a black box. The important point I guess is that this process uses the same input values for each vertex.

Comment: Also, does a GPU process generate these "points", or do they come from the CPU?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is arbitrary amplification of geometry: taking one point primitive and producing arbitrarily many entirely separate primitives from it. And the tool GPUs have for that is geometry shaders (or just using a compute shader to generate your vertex data manually, but that's probably not faster and *definitely* more memory consuming).

While GS's are not known for performance, there is one way you might be able to speed up what you're doing. Since all of the primitives in a particular call will generate a specific number of primitives, you can eschew having each GS output more than one primitive by employing vertex [instanced rendering](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing).

Here, you use `glDrawArraysInstanced`. Your VS needs to pass `gl_InstanceID` to the GS, which can use that to figure out which triangle to generate from the vertex. That is, instead of having a loop over `n` to generate `n` triangles, the GS only generates one triangle. But it gets called `instanceCount` times, and each call should generate the `gl_InstanceID`th triangle.

Now, one downside of this is that the order of triangles generated will be different. In your original GS code, where each GS generates all of the triangles from a point, all of the triangles from one point will be rendered *before* rendering any triangles from another point. With vertex instancing, you get one triangle from all of the points, then it produces another triangle from all the points, etc. If rendering order matters to you, then this won't work.

If that's important, then you can try [geometry shader instancing](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Instancing) instead. This works similarly to vertex instancing, except that the instance count is part of the GS. Each GS invocation is only responsible for a single triangle, and you use `gl_InvocationID` to decide which triangle to use it on. This will ensure that all primitives from one set of GS instances will be rendered before any primitives from a different set of GS instances.

The downside is what I said: the instance count is *part of the GS*. Unlike instanced rendering, the number of instances is baked into the GS code itself. So you will need a separate program for *every* count of triangles you work with. [SPIR-V specialization constants](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/SPIR-V#Entry_points_and_specialization) make it a bit easier on you to build those programs, but you still need to maintain (and swap) multiple programs.

Also, while instanced rendering has no limit on the number of instances, GS's do have a limit. And that limit can be as small as 32 (which is a [very popular number](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/displaycapability.php?name=GL_MAX_GEOMETRY_SHADER_INVOCATIONS)).